# Weak and Weak star convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X$ a Banach space, and $x_n\in X$, $f_n\in X'$ sequences. Show that:

1. If $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ on $x$, and $f_n\to f$ on $X'$, then $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$.
2. If $x_n\to x$ on $X$ and $f_{n} \rightharpoonup^* f $, then $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$.

I tried:

1. By definition, $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ means that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, for all $f\in X'$, so for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
   $$n\geq n_0\quad \Rightarrow \quad\|f(x_n) -f(x)\|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}...............(\alpha)$$

Also, because $f_n\to f$ on $X'$, there is $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
$$\forall x\in X, n\geq n_1\quad \Rightarrow\quad \|f_n(x) -f(x)\|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
In particular, for $x_n\in X$,
$$n\geq n_1\quad \Rightarrow\quad \|f_n(x_n) -f(x_n)\|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}...........(\beta)$$
So, let $N=\max\{n_0,n_1\}$ and $x\in X$. By ($\alpha$) and ($\beta$), if $n\geq N$

$$\|f_n(x_n)-f(x)\|\leq \|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\|+\|f(x_n)-f(x)\|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$

So $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$.

**edited**
2. By definition, as $f_{n} \rightharpoonup^* f $, then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$, for all $x\in X$, then
$$\sup\{\|f_n(x)\|;n\in\mathbb{N}\}<\infty$$
By Banach-Steinhaus there is $C>0$ such that
$$\|f_n\|\leq C,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Hence
$$|f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|\leq \|f_n\|\cdot \|x-x_n\|\leq C\|x-x_n\|, \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.........(I)  $$

Using, triangular inequality, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\leq |f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|.$$
Using (I) above we get
 $$ |f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\leq C\|x-x_n\|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}....(II)$$

Because $f$ is continuous, $x_n\to x$ em $X$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ so 
$$\|x-x_n\|\to 0\quad e\quad |f(x_n)-f(x)|\to 0.$$
Taking limit in (II) when $n\to\infty$, finally we get 
$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\to 0,$$
i.e.
$$\boxed{f_n(x_n)\to f(x).}$$

Are they correct?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks good to me.  Some quantifiers are misplaced though. Weak* convergence is 
 pointwise convergence of the operators $\mu_n.$ However, convergence/strong convergence of $\mu_n$ to $µ$  uniform. You should take care of this thing.

Comment: In the first case, do you want to consider strong convergence of $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$? In any case, the line between $(\alpha)$ and $(\beta)$ needs some explanation. The definition of $f_n \rightarrow f$ only gives that $\Vert f_n - f \Vert \rightarrow 0$, not that $\forall x \in X: \Vert f_n(x) - f(x) \Vert \rightarrow 0$. It does imply that too, but thats not clear a priori.

Comment: thank you very much, i edited item 2, i am having problem with item 1.